# Form doesn't upload file

Tags: php, forms, blob

I have a problem with uploading an img, php is shouting out that $_FILES is empty or to be more specific:

```
Notice: Undefined index: newAvatar [...]
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null [...]
```

This is my form:

```
<form action="updateAvatar.php" method="post" id="updateAvatarForm" enctype=”multipart/form-data”>
  <div class="changeAvatar">
     <div class="avatar">
       <img src=<?php echo ($_SESSION['profile'] != NULL) ?  base64_encode($_SESSION['profile']) : "../static/img/blankProfilePic.svg";?> alt="" id="avatarPreview">
       <input type="file" name="newAvatar" id="newAvatar">
       <img src="../static/img/changeProfilePic.svg" alt="" id="changeAvatar">
     </div>
   </div>
 </form>
```

and simple php image printer:

```
<?php
  echo '<img src='.$_FILES["newAvatar"]["name"].'>';
?>
```

form is submitting by eventListener in js:

```
    newAvatar.addEventListener("change", ()=>{
            updateAvatarForm.submit()
    });
```

I've tried to add some prop's like "ajax-something" to the form, set timeout in js cuz I thought maybe submit is firing too fast but I'm stuck, everything I've tried doesn't work...

If someone could help I would be grateful, sorry for my english which isn't my native language.

Comment: `enctype=”multipart/form-data”` check your quotation marks is this a typo? `enctype="multipart/form-data"` try this way

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much! So little thing and so problematic ;x